How to reduce time complexity to ship items
I have a vehicle that has a maximum capacity to carry items per trip and for each trip, it can pick max_items items of same type.
Return the minimum number of trips needed by the vehicle.
Example:
I have an items array, where items[i] indicates the number of items of type i.
items = [4,4,3]
vehicle capacity per trip = 3
max items same type allowed per trip is 3
output is 4
Constraints:
n is items list size, 1 <= n <= 10^5
1 <= items[i] <= 10^5
1<= capacity <= 10^5
1 <= max_allowed_same_type <= 10^5
Here is my code:
public static long solve(List<Integer> items, int capacity, int max_allowed_same_type) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    pq.addAll(items);

    long result = 0;
    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        int load = 0;
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        while (load < capacity && !pq.isEmpty()) {
            int item = pq.poll();
            int minItem = Math.min(max_allowed_same_type, item);
            int e = load + minItem;
            if (e > capacity) {
                int diff = capacity - load;
                pq.add(item - diff);
                break;
            } else {
                load += minItem;
            }
            if (item > minItem) {
                temp.add(item - minItem);
            }
        }
        pq.addAll(temp);
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Test case 1
    System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(4, 4, 3), 3, 3)); // 4

    // Test case 2
    System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 2, 6), 2, 1)); // 7

    // Test case 3 (the one that was failing)
    System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(1, 4), 1, 2)); // 5

}

I am not sure, what will be the time complexity for this code. I am assuming the time the complexity of my code is O(sum(items)) in the worst case, correct me if I am wrong here. What is the correct approach to solve this problem in less time complexity.

Ok my first question would be, what is the issue you have with time complexity ? You two loops, but first loop is quite normal because it checks that queue is not empty.

@драган-јованковић, I posted constraints of my problem, so if input is large my code is not time efficient.

@CodeCrusader did you try using a simple for loop and create number of trips for each item ? Using some Math formula maybe ?

@драган-јованковић, I don't think we can solve this using some Math formula. Can you suggest if you found out a formula?

@драган-јованковић, can you please share the math formula you were referring to.

How does [4,4,3], capacity=3, items=3 solve to give 3? I calculate the minimum is \ceil(\sum_i items=11/3)=4?

@Neil, 4 is correct answer, I updated the question.

seems like a harder variation of this problem which is np-hard

I don't quite understand your code; is temp an augmenting path? Is this Edmonds-Karp? You could try Ford–Fulkerson if you don't mind it being quasi-polynomial.
